# Is there an estimate of average (e.g. monthly) gas usage per user?

Tags: gas, gas-estimate

With the whole discussion around "network value", I'm wondering how much gas the average account uses on a periodical basis.

Let's say that the relevant account pool consists of any account that has interacted with the rest of the network in recent times, e.g. six months. Of course, any transaction goes, whether simple value transaction, contract deployment or contract call.

**Is there a way to figure out the average gas used for any such account?** Can also be total usage since inception of network if the alternative is too complicated.

Answer (score 3):

[EthGasStation](http://ethgasstation.info/index.php) has some data in Misc. statistics.

In the last 2,500 blocks

- Contracts: Median Gas Per Call    42840
- Contracts: Median Gas Fee     $0.125
- Total Transactions (last 10k blocks)  255090
- Total Transfers   146778 (58%)
- Total Contract Calls  108312 (42%)

Perhaps you can suggest them an average per address.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was removed from ethgasstation. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anywhere that this calculation is made available.

The way to figure it out would be to manually pull the gas from each transaction in the time window you wanted, add it up and average it by the total number of accounts. Whether accounts is just externally owned accounts or it also includes contracts would be your decision. External accounts only is probably easier and closer to what you're looking for, but note that accounts may be shared and that a single user can create more than one account (such as an exchange, which will have many accounts). You could probably query a block explorer, but seeing as it would take a lot of queries it may be worth just running a node yourself.